# Deferred Query Iteration in Linq to Entities

Tags: silverlight, linq, mvvm

I have a problem in understanding the LINQ to Entites query which does not give me the desired results. I have the following code, which should execute the deferred query and show the results in Silverlight Datagrid.

```
  public List<DispIRTSiteReports> DisplayIRTSiteReportsFilOn(List<IssueTypes> issueType, DateTime fDate, DateTime tDate)
  {

  try
        {

            var resultSet = from items in DataContext.IRT_Limited_View
                            select items;

            var iType = issueType.Select(i=>i.IssueName); //contains multiple selected issue type Names

            if (issueType.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var type in iType)
                {
                    var copy = type;
                    resultSet = resultSet.Where(items => items.Type_Text.Equals(copy));                       
                }                    
            }

            var newResultSet = (from q in resultSet
                                where q.Date_Time > fDate && q.Date_Time < tDate
                                select new DispIRTSiteReports
                                {                                        
                                    PhExt = q.Phone_Extension,
                                    IssueType = q.Type_Text,
                                    IssueSubType = q.Subtype_Text,
                                    IssueDes = q.Issue_Description
                                }).ToList();

            return newResultSet;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

}

I select multiple IssueType Names and they are stored in var iType, but when I execute the code, the resultSet contains null as the first "foreach" iteration alters the resultSet with the first issueType Name and when second iteration is done, the resultSet cannot match the second IssueType Name and thus the resultSet becomes null.

I would like to know how to query the resultSet without altering the original resultSet so that the resultSet contains the corresponding data of multiple IssueType Names selected. Your help in this regard is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is `DispIRTSiteReports` entity added to metadata manually or its a part of generated entities?

Comment: The DispIRTSiteReports is a class which conttains getter, setter methods for the IssueType ID and IssueType Name fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you add the predicates, which translates into `AND`. If you use `Contains` you get the same semantics as `OR`:

```
resultSet = resultSet.Where(items => iType.Contains(items.Type_Text));
```

(Note: no `foreach` loop)

Comment: Hi GertArnold, Your solution worked like charm. But I am unable to understand the solution, can you explain me in layman terms why my code was not working and your's works (I don't understand predicate means). Just curious to understand what I made wrong.

Comment: A predicate is a function that returns a boolean (also: a condition). So the lambda expression in a Where statement is a predicate. If you make a chain of Where statements (as you did in the foreach) the conditions are connected by `AND` (conjunction). The Contains expresses that Type_Text can have any value in iType, which is the same as `OR`.

Comment: Hi GertArnold, Thanks for the explanation. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `DispIRTSiteReports` as `DataContract`:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class DispIRTSiteReports
{                                             
   [Key]
   [DataMember]
   public long Id { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public string PhExt { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public string IssueType { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public string IssueSubType { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public string IssueDes { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully this will help.